# Android: how to create shape with skewed two-tone color?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-shape

I am attempting to create a drawable shape that will become the background of a search bar. I know how to create a rectangle with two colors but I do not know how to tilt the color at an angle, like in the second image. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: easiest way would be to take image as background

Comment: Try to adjust topLeftRadius of Corners attribute. Or create a 9-patch image.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will have a go and see which one fits my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a Toolbar...code is here...

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background" />
```

create a drawable res file custom_background.xml and

In that toolbar set drawable like this....code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="500dp"
            android:height="50dp" />
        <solid android:color="#0072BC" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="8dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="-400dp"
    android:right="128dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="160">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this programmatically in Kotlin? My question is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811698/what-is-the-android-version-of-css-transform-in-html .