# How to create a slanted button?

Tags: android, button

i'm looking for how to create a slanted button like the picture :

[image]

i tried some solutions : [How to create parallelogram shape background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094070/how-to-create-parallelogram-shape-background) 
and

[Android: how to create shape with skewed two-tone color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893512/android-how-to-create-shape-with-skewed-two-tone-color)
But I could not find what I was looking for

Comment: "But I could not find what I was looking for" doesn't say much.

Comment: yor can give rotation to your view with setRotation method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third party library, can give slanted shape Textview. you can set a listener to Textview and perform your desired function. You can change the direction of SlantedTextView by changing the value of app:slantedMode="left" and also can increase and decrease the size of SlantedTextView by changing the value of app:slantedLength="55dp".

**Library:**

```
compile 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.2'
```

**Link:** https://github.com/HeZaiJin/SlantedTextView`

**XML Code:**

```
<com.haozhang.lib.SlantedTextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:slantedBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:slantedLength="55dp"
    app:slantedMode="left"
    app:slantedText="IOS"
    app:slantedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:slantedTextSize="16sp" />
```

**Java Code:**

```
SlantedTextView stv = (SlantedTextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

stv.setText("PHP")
        .setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        .setSlantedBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        .setTextSize(18)
        .setSlantedLength(50)
        .setMode(SlantedTextView.MODE_LEFT);
```

[image]

If you want something similar then I have written some code in drawable. May be It can help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="43dp"
        android:left="43dp"
        android:right="43dp"
        android:top="43dp">

        <rotate android:fromDegrees="10">

            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="200dp"
                    android:height="200dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#ecf566"
                    android:startColor="#00000000" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#1414d2" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]