# What is the android version of css transform in html

Tags: android, kotlin

In css for html there are a number of different things that you can do with the `transform` attribute. [this link has more detail on what i'm speaking about](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

I want to learn how to do this in android (weather it can easily be done in xml or programmatically on kotlin).

This is what i know so far:

- RotateX() translates to `android:rotationX=""`
- RotateY() translates to `android:rotationY=""`
- RotateZ() translates to `android:rotation=""`

Here is what i don't know but really want to find out:

- SkewX() translates to currently Unknown. ([this link shows you what SkewX() does in html](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skewx))
- SkewY() translates to currently Unknown. ([this link shows you what SkewY() does in html](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_skewy))

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375130/skewing-a-text-view-in-android) gives a good simple answer to both the questions with `canvas?.skew(1.0f, 0.3f)` inside the `ondraw` listener however, it only skews the text and not the shape of the view unlike the html version shown in the links.

How do i do the unknown ones (SkewX and SkewY) mentioned above?